# How do I block power from going to usb without stopping data transfer?

Tags: ipad, imac, usb, power

I need an iPad connected to my iMac for a long time, but I don't want power going to it because leaving an iPad charged to 100% all the time ruins the life of the battery([link](https://www.apple.com/batteries/maximizing-performance/)). I still want to allow data transfer, but with no charge(or extremely little like when it says "Not Charging") going to my device.

Comment: New Apple products won't overcharge.
They'll charge to 100% then drop to 97% or so then back up and will continue repeating this cycle to avoid damaging the battery.

[Source](http://allthingsd.com/20120327/apple-ipad-battery-nothing-to-get-charged-up-about/)

Comment: Where does it say "leaving an iPad charged to 100% all the time ruins the life of the batter"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this. You could *try* to rewire a USB cable with the power wire removed. There's a chance this would work, but I wouldn't bet on it, it would depend on how the iPad handles USB connections.

You won't ruin your battery by having it plugged in at 100%. This might be an issue if you're leaving it 24 hours a day, but Apple is smart enough not to let their batteries die from being plugged in.

Comment: [USB needs a power line to provide data transfer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178286/usb-data-transfer-without-charge).

Comment: I assumed as much, although I've found a few specific reports of people trying this with a USB DAC. It almost certainly won't work with an iPad. http://www.computeraudiophile.com/f8-general-forum/universal-serial-bus-industry-standard-cables-connectors-and-communications-protocols-between-computers-and-electronic-devices-cable-no-vcc-and-ground-16299/